# MySQL: Select records that don't have transitive child records

Tags: mysql, sql, select, filter, left-join

I will illustrate my question as I understand it's very confusing.

Say you have three tables (data is not consistent it's only for illustrative purposes):

**Category**

```
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | History  |
| 2  | Sci-fi   |
| 3  | Mystery  |
+----+----------+
```

**Book**

```
+----+-----------------------------+
| id | category_id | name          |
+----+-------------+---------------+
| 1  | 5           | Mowgli        |
| 2  | 7           | Don Quixote   |
| 3  | 11          | Ulysses       |
+----+-------------+---------------+
```

**Tags**

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | book_id | name        |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 1  | 452     | Bestseller  |
| 2  | 42      | Novel       |
| 3  | 921     | Novelty     |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

I need to select all unassigned tags for each book.

Below is the query that simply shows all tags per category, per book, where I need (I'm repeating myself here) to select only those tags that are assigned to any other book but not the current one.

Or in other words to only select tags that haven't yet been assigned to the book.

```
SELECT c.id category_id, b.name, t.book_id, t.id tag_id 
FROM tags t
LEFT JOIN book b ON b.id=t.book_id
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id=b.category_id
```

Comment: Show the results you want.  What does `category` have to do with the question?

Comment: I feel like with your setup of tags you should probably just have the tags be their own table, so that the list of tags remains fixed, while creating a new table that links the two things.

Comment: All comments and answers are the point. I didn't fully understand the problem when I asked the question hence some of the things I asked didn't quite connect. Thank you everyone to their input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use `cross join` to generate all combinations of books and tags.  Then use `left join` or some other method to filter out the ones that already exist:

```
select b.*, t.name
from (select distinct name from tags) t cross join
     books b left join
     tags tt
     on tt.book_id = b.id and tt.name = t.name
where tt.book_id is null
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!